# when ODE changes for parts of output

Tags: differential-equations

```
UD[s_]=Piecewise[{{Cos[V[s]],Z[s]<1},{1-U[s]/2,Z[s]>1&&Z[s]<4}}]
VD[s_]=Piecewise[{{Sin[U[s]],Z[s]<1},{1-V[s]/3.,Z[s]>1&&Z[s]<4}}]
ZD[s_]=Cos[U[s]]*Cos[V[s]]
            NDSolve[{U'[s]==UD[s],V'[s]==V[s],Z'[s]==ZD[s],U[0]==.1,V[0]==.3,Z[0]==0.2},{U,V,Z},{s,0,6}]
    {ph[t_],si[t_],z[t]}={U[t],V[t],Z[t]}/.First[%];
    Plot[{ph[s],si[s],z[s]},{s,0,6}]
    ParametricPlot[{{z[s],si[s]/100.},{z[s],ph[s]}},{s,0,6},PlotLabel-> "si,ph",PlotRange->All];
```

How is it written when ode itself is changing for different parts of output (Z) through a changing input function (U,V) switch? I have no clue where the disconnect is.Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UD[s_] := 
  Piecewise[{{Cos[V[s]], Z[s] < 1}, {1 - U[s]/2, 
     Z[s] > 1 && Z[s] < 4}}];
VD[s_] := 
  Piecewise[{{Sin[U[s]], Z[s] < 1}, {1 - V[s]/3., 
     Z[s] > 1 && Z[s] < 4}}];
ZD[s_] := Cos[U[s]]*Cos[V[s]];
sol = NDSolve[{U'[s] == UD[s], V'[s] == V[s], Z'[s] == ZD[s], 
    U[0] == .1, V[0] == .3, Z[0] == 0.2}, {U, V, Z}, {s, 0, 6}];

Plot[Evaluate[{U[s], V[s], Z[s]} /. First[sol]], {s, 0, 6}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"U", "V", "Z"}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Thanks. The paramtericPlot added does not go upto $z=6$ but it may have to do with the model itself. Corrected the typos.